# Scrapy, scrape links and then scrape page

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am fairly comfortable with scraping sites in this format:
Stsrt page > page 1 > page 2 > the page I want to scrape

But I am a little stuck when it comes to a site where each page has a number of links to the pages I want to scrape.

I am thinking that I need to first crawl and scrape all the links I need, in this formate:
Page 1, scrape all links, follow to page 2 > page 2, scrape all links, follow to page 3 * repeat for X number of pages * > then once all links are established, follow and scrape the data I want.

Would the best way to do this be to use a function to create a list of the links and then pass that to a function which iterates through them and scrapes the data?

Comment: Yes, best approach would be to create a list of listing pages and then scrape products.

Comment: @Pushplata, great, thank you! Have really struggled to find some use cases on this type!

Comment: Yes, i have crawled more than 1 millions of url for a price comparison portal and  experienced this as the best way to scrape data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the scraping the data is the same for each link then yes.

You would get something like this:

```
for link in links:
    scrape_date(link)
```

where `links` is the list with all the links on all the pages you scraped before.

You could also scrape the data from all the links found on every page at the same time. Something like this:

```
for page in pages:
    urls = scrape_urls(page)
    data = scrape_date(urls)
```

where `pages` is a list of all the pages (page 1, page 2, page 3, etc.).